# Describing "at least" using logical connectives.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If s, j, and b are logical statements, how do I express the statement "s is true and at least one of the others is false"? Is it $s\wedge (\neg j \vee \neg b)$? But wouldn't there be a case for $\neg j \vee \neg b$ where it is false?

I was reading the answer to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149031/using-the-statement-at-least-in-propositional-logic), and they used the or connective only.

Comment: For the given statement to be true, $s$ has to be true and one of $j$ or $b$ has to be False. So, for the case when $\neg j \vee \neg b$ is False, the given statement itself would be False.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Oh! I understand now. Thanks so much!